# OPC server built in to dymosim.exe cannot be found by OPC client on localhost

Tags: opc

According to the Dymola user guide:

1. It is possible to start Dymosim from an OPC client. To enable this,
   the environment variable PATH needs to be complemented with the path
   to the Dymola installation directories bin and bin\lib
2. The Dymosim OPC server is registered automatically each time a new
   model translation is performed in Dymola.
3. Although the Dymosim OPC servercan be started from Dymola or called
   directly by the user, the normal procedure is to start it from an
   OPC client, in which Dymosim will show up as Dymosim.OPCServer.1

I have compiled my model in Dymola with the option of an imbedded OPC Server. If I run the resulting dymosim.exe file from within the Dymola Modelling Environment, or even manually by clicking on the dymosim.exe file, then the OPC server is initialized and simulation occurs in realtime. Now the problem:

I wish to now start the imbedded OPC Server from an OPC UA client. With reference to the three points above:

1. Completed.
2. No evidence that the OPC server is ever registered (in the windows
   registry, I assume). I have monitored all registry processes on my
   machine using the Sysinternals Suite at time of model
   translation/compilation but see no evidence of this step occurring.
3. Because step 2 (registering the Dymosim OPC Server) does not seem to
   be occuring, I am not surprised that the imbedded server
   Dymosim.OPCServer.1 does not show up in any of the UA Clients I have
   tested.

Note: I have installed OPC test servers which register at installation and show up as expected in the OPC client. So the problem does not lie with the OPC Client.

I am fairly sure the problem lies with Dymola not registering the imbedded OPC Server in the windows registry.

I am running a node-locked installation of Dymola and am performing all the OPC server-client interactions on the localhost.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated.

Clifford

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, start Dymola.exe with Administrator rights. This allows the imbedded OPC server (in dymosim.exe) to be registered in the Windows registry at model translation.

Comment: I am newbie to this, where I can find dymosim.exe can you help

Comment: on simulating my FLUIDWORKING.mo file in dymola                                                        
                                                                                                                                            I get this info

Comment: ````Log-file of program ./dymosim

dymosim started
                                                                                                                                          Model: FluidWORKING
                                                                                                                                          ... "dsin.txt" loading (dymosim input file)
                                                                                                                                          ... "FluidWORKING.mat" creating 
... "dsfinal.txt" creating````